# “Playing back” data from a pandas data frame with a date time column in real time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big pandas data frame with a datetime column of when sensor data came in. I want to create an application that plays back this data in “real time”. For example, a user could scrub across a timeline like a video player and it would jump to the correct row and snag data at the correct time intervals, press play, and go through and display the data in the real time it came in.

What is the most efficient way to loop over this data frame and snag the row in real-time playback?

Comment: maybe `pandas_alive` python package could help?

Answer (score 0):

The core of this requirement is to realize the scrolling effect. You can refer to this code. Of course, there are special components on JavaScript to set the timeline. You can add JavaScript tags to your problems and let the front-end engineer help you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{margin:0;padding:0;}
        .box{
            width:500px;
            height:350px;
            margin:100px auto;
            border:1px solid #000;
            border-radius:20px;
            box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #333;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        h3{
            height:50px;
            line-height:50px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:28px;
            color:#fff;
            background:green;
        }
        .content{
            height:300px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        ul li{
            list-style:none;
            height:40px;
            line-height:40px;
            text-align:left;
            padding-left:20px;
            font-size:18px;
            color:#333;
        }
        li:hover{color:#f91;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <h3>datalist</h3>
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <ul class="msg1" id="msg1">
            <li></li>
            <li>pandas data1</li>
            <li>pandas data2</li>
            <li>pandas data3</li>
            <li>pandas data4</li>
            <li>pandas data5</li>
            <li>pandas data6</li>
            <li>pandas data7</li>
            <li>pandas data8</li>
            <li>pandas data9</li>
            <li>pandas data10</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="msg2"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var content=document.getElementById("content");
    var msg1=document.getElementById("msg1");
    var msg2=document.getElementById("msg2");
    msg2.innerHTML=msg1.innerHTML;
    var timer=1;
    content.scrollTop=0;
    function myScrollTop(){
        if(content.scrollTop>content.scrollHeight){
            content.scrollTop=0;
        }else{
            content.scrollTop++
        }
    }
    upScroll = setInterval('myScrollTop()',timer);
    content.onmouseover=function(){
      clearInterval(upScroll);
    };
    content.onmouseout=function(){
        upScroll = setInterval('myScrollTop()',timer);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Confused by this response. I am trying to loop over a pandas data frame in Python in real time…not looking for a JavaScript or web solution

Comment: @CyberBully2003 you should provide a clear input/output example in your question